# How to block access to public/assets from url in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I'm working on a Ruby On Rails app and I'm calling some js, css, images and csv files from public/assets.

I added an authentication when accessing the page using these assets:

```
class MyPageController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate

    def index
    end

    def authenticate
        authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
            username == 'login' && password == 'password'
        end
    end
end
```

and it works for this page but if I type `localhost:3000/assets/myFile.csv` I can access it and download it without being asked for authentication.

Is there a way to add an authentication on that url or to block it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need them to be blocked, then it's better to move them to a different folder. The intention of that folder is to hold publicly accessible static files.